# telnet on hosted machine running on azure devops pipeline

Tags: android, azure-devops, telnet, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Here is my detail about my problem:

**what I want to achieve:**

create a pipeline on azure DevOps, containing tasks

1. create android emulator with internet condition full
2. run some tests
3. connect telnet
4. connect telnet to android console port- send command to android device to change nework condition to low bandwidth as mentioned here (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)

**Note:** I have hosted MacOS, also telnet+expect and spawn is installed over it

**What is the problem:**

5. My android device is running over 5037 port
6. telnet task output showing me "telnet connected to local host" command I am using to connect to android console port is  :  telnet localhost 5037   (in a command line task)
7. escape character is "^]"
   **
8. it is not showing me any authentication required message or OK so I can go ahead with it, also I am trying to send command like expect"^]" returning me nothing

**
I want to run **emulator -netspeed gsm @Pixel_API_26**   please help